# When was kosher certification created?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, kashering-kosherization, restaurant

When was kosher certification created? Another way of saying this question was when did the Rabbis say that it was appropriate to have a governing body (such as the OU, Star-K etc...) which oversees and certifies products and establishments as kosher?

In addition to this, what did people do prior to having a governing body? Did they eat products where the ingredients didn't specify anything that wasn't Kosher? Did people eat at all types restaurants? (this probably has bishul akum problems associated I assume)

Were any Rabbis opposed to creating a body which governed Kashrus?

Comment: שמן זית למנורה ...

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59771/759