# Source for requirement of 3rd party hechsher?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher

When you eat another Jew's food, you are entitled to rely on him for the kashrus of the food.  By that reasoning, if he opens a restaurant, and you know him to be Yarei Shamayim, you shouldn't need any external certifying authority to eat there.

But I've been told that as soon as someone opens an eatery for profit, one can no longer rely on his personal Yiras Shamayim, but you need a 3rd party to certify his kashrus.

Is that true?  If so, please quote sources.

Comment: It's not a matter of for profit. Its a matter of Jews living in large cities that lack the central Beis Din that would (at times literally) whip people into shape. So now, how could anyone know anyone or trust anyone well enough to eat by him? There are many restaurants I can think of where the customers that eat there would not eat in the owners home, but trust the mashgiach to eat in the store. I am not endorsing such behavior, just pointing out that it exists.

Comment: @user6591 This would be because they trust the rav who certifies the mashgiach to be trustworthy. Thus, (as an example) they would eat in the Rav's home or trust the rav to allow them to eat in the home of someone that he trusts. The rules of kashrus in a restaurant could be more complex than in the individual home as well.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6543

Comment: @sabbahillel yes, trusting the Rav was my point. Complexity is probably not the issue as no new rules have been invented in the last hundred years. It's more the lack of impetus to call a rabbi when something happens, again the issue being the lack of strong central religious governing.

Comment: @msh210 My question is *similar* to the one you linked, but it's not a duplicate.  I'm looking for *sources*.  Besides which, the linked question doesn't have any accepted answers, just a lot of discussion.

Comment: @user6591 The point is that, as an example, someone from another town would not always be able to call at any time. A teudah from a rav and a mashgiach certified by the rav allows anyone frome anywhere to use the restaurant without having to search the city for information.

Comment: @sabbahillel and what did the millions of visitors to Jerusalem in temple tines do? How about the millions living in Alexandria? Inns were very common throughout Europe. There were never teudos.

Comment: Any answer to any question should ideally include sources. Both questions want to know whether a restaurant needs certification; in fact, both ask in the context of generally trusting another Jew's food. I don't see how it's not a duplicate. If there aren't good answers there, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers.

Comment: @user6591 Circumstances were different then. You are asking about modern times. In fact, nowadays not even a certification posted in the window can always be trusted.

Comment: @Sabbahillel my comment addressed what is different. I am not asking anything. Btw it's a bit ironic that in the question marked as a duplicate with this one, you basically answered what I wrote in my comment here. And yet you are continuing a twelve hour long argument against that very theory. Of course now you've Ben backed into a corner of trying to differentiate between your answer there and many comment here which is something I'm not really interested in hearing. Its just something I'm pointing out to you, for you to think about.